# Mandrill template merge fail

Tags: ruby, templates, mandrill

I'm using mandrill to send emails from my API (in ruby with the mandrill-api gem), like signup confirmation email.

I have a merge tag in the template to put the username :

> Hello *|USERNAME|*,
>
> Thank you very much for installing the app! ...
>   ...

My ruby code looks like that :

```
m = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_KEY']
template_name = "app-registration-welcome-email"
template_content = [{}]
message = {
  :from_name=> "From Name",
  :to=>[
    {
      :email => user.email,
      :name => user.name,
    }
  ],
  :global_merge_vars => [{
    :name => "username",
    :content => user.name
  }],
  :merge_language => "mailchimp",
  :merge => true,
  :merge_vars => [{
    :rcpt => user.email,
    :vars => [{
      :name => "username",
      :content => user.name
    }],
  }],
  :track_opens => true,
}
m.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
```

Unfortunately, when i receive the email, all is fine (to, name, from, ...) but the merge tag isn't replaced in the body and i still have `*|USERNAME|*` displayed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which gem are you using? There are a large number of ruby wrappers for the mandrill API. https://mandrillapp.com/docs/integrations.html

Comment: It's mandrill-api, i just updated the message with this information, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to set `USERNAME` once, either in `:global_merge_vars` or `:merge_vars`.

- If you're sending to just one recipient, it doesn't matter which you do.
- If there are multiple recipients, use `:merge_vars`.

Try building `message` and then `puts message.to_json` and drop it into the debugger at https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template (Click the 'Try it' button.) See if that gives you any clues.

You might also try using "USERNAME" instead of "username" as your variable name. The docs say merge vars are case-insensitive, but it's worth removing one more possible mismatch.

Comment: yes, that's because i already tried all of these possibilities. I will try the debugger, i didn't know about it. Thanks, i'll keep you posted

Comment: awesome! glad to hear it! what was the actual problem?